# Session variables not saving when using ngrok with host header rewrite - Laravel

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-7, ngrok

I need to use NGROK for one part of my app. I use `ngrok http -host-header=rewrite localhost:8000` for everything to properly load (js/css). The issue I am coming across is I set Session variables after the user clicks a button.

The session is not being saved to the ngrok URL. I'm guessing because its a header rewrite.

I've tried changing the `SESSION_DOMAIN`, `path`, and even played around with `same_site`. Nothing seems to be working.

If I click the button using just 'localhost:8000', the session saves but now the rest of my app broken since I need a ngrok instance.

Is there any workaround to save session variables to the ngrok url? Or somehow coonfigure this differently?

I am using Laravel 7.3